# Splitting a double vector into equal parts

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Greetings,

Any input on a way to divide a std::vector into two equal parts ? I need to find the smallest possible difference between |part1 - part2|.

This is how I'm doing it now, but from what you can probably tell it will yield a non-optimal split in some cases.

```
auto mid = std::find_if(prim, ultim, [&](double temp) -> bool
{
    if(tempsum >= sum)
        return true;

    tempsum += temp;
    sum -= temp;
    return false;
});
```

The vector is sorted, highest to lowest, values can indeed appear twice.
I'm not expecting part1 and part2 to have the same numbers of elements, but sum(part1) should be as close as possible to sum(part2)

For example if we would have { 2.4, 0.12, 1.26, 0.51, 0.70 }, the best split would be { 2.4, 0.12 } and { 1.26, 0.51, 0.70 }.

If it helps, I'm trying to achieve the splitting algorithm for the Shannon Fano encoding.

Maybe this will help you guys understand my question better http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding#Example

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to extend what your requirements are. The description is missing important bits of information like whether only the split point can be moved or if elements can also be moved from one part of the vector to the other...

Comment: Could you please give us additional information about how the values are stored in the vector ? Is it sorted ? Can they appear twice ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the smallest possible difference between |part1 - part2|"? Are we talking about `|sum(part1) - sum(part2)|`? Are you expecting `part1` and `part2` to have the same number of elements?

Comment: It is possible to pick the 1st, 3rd and 5th items in part1 and the 2nd and 4th in part2 ?

Comment: Ehm, you say you want optimal code, but implement shannon fano, which has the problem of not being optimal :p.

Comment: On how simple algorithms can be implemented completely wrong as using a LAMBDA expression can give you some reputation.

Comment: You're saying the vector is sorted from highest to lowest, yet it is not in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that:

```
The vector is sorted, highest to lowest, values can indeed appear twice.
I'm not expecting part1 and part2 to have the same numbers of elements, but
sum(part1) should be as close as possible to sum(part2)
```

This is not optimal, but it will provide a reasonable approximation for values such as those you have given (unless I mucked something up ... I didn't actually compile or test it).  It also works if you have negative numbers in the original vector:

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double> >
    split(const std::vector<double>& data)
{
    std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double> > rv;
    double s1=0.0, s2=0.0;
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator i;

    for (i=data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
    {
        double dif1 = abs(*i + s1 - s2);
        double dif2 = abs(*i + s2 - s1);

        if (dif1 < dif2)
        {
            rv.first.push_back(*i);
            s1 += *i;
        }
        else
        {
            rv.second.push_back(*i);
            s2 += *i;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

**EDIT:** The quality of the result will be lower with this approach if there the sum of the negative numbers in your vector overwhelms the sum of the positive numbers in the list.  To resolve, you could try to order the original list by descending absolute value rather than in strictly descending order.

Comment: This seems incorrect if one looks at the wikipedia entry: in the wikipedia entry the list is sorted (decreasing) and the partitioning involves finding a split point within this list, putting the highest elements in one set and the lowest in another... though the wikipedia example seems suboptimal in this regard.

Comment: This is the greedy algorithm that they mention and briefly describe.

Comment: @Matthieu: The split isn't a pivot split but rather a partitioning of the data; elements 1 and 3 can go to sublist 1 while elements 2 and 4 can go to sublist 2

Answer (score 3):

This is a [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is known to be NP-Complete, so no polynomial-time algorithm exists in general. However, the problem becomes easier when the sizes of the elements in the set are bounded. Above link to Wikipedia has quite a nice section on approximation algorithms (when you need a "good-enough" solution).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use std algorithms and lambdas you could do the following

```
void splitProbabilityVector(std::vector<double>& data, std::vector<double>& rightHandSplit)
{
    double s1=0.0, s2=0.0;
    auto bound = std::stable_partition(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](double e) -> bool
    {
        if (abs(e + s1 - s2) < abs(e + s2 - s1))
        { s1 += e; return true;}
        else
        { s2 += e; return false; }
    });

    rightHandSplit.assign(bound, data.end());
    data.resize(bound-data.begin());
}
```

which should be quite performant. Just out of curiosity, why are you using this algorithm when on the wiki page you linked it states:

> For this reason, Shannon–Fano is
>   almost never used; Huffman coding is
>   almost as computationally simple and
>   produces prefix codes that always
>   achieve the lowest expected code word
>   length.

Comment: Well the assignment was to analyze a text and compare the results yielded by both methods, to compute the medium code length for each one

Comment: Ah! comparison... great stuff - I loved your use of c++0x in your questions example code btw.